# Help installing Spring plugin on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, p2

I have been trying for weeks to install spring plugin with Eclipse 3.7

It seems very slow and it keeps timing out with certain jars it is trying to get as dependancies
tptp jars are the usual problems, Is there any way to manually install these dependancies and the plugin or do i have to keep trying over and over watching it re-download the same files over and over?

I did leave it once all day Friday through to end of day Monday and it only got 48% through installing.

Repository in use is the following

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.7

and

http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/composite/e3.7

I am on a fast link but just got this error

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Unable to read repository at http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.6/plugins/com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver_1.6.10.RELEASE.jar.
>   Read timed out
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.springsource.sts.config.ui,2.7.1.201107091000-RELEASE.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: a311d3e2326d8a267f1531ff26c16e4b and found 7d163b4dd2819f5b24ff2272c54bbe0d.
>   Unable to read repository at http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.6/plugins/com.springsource.sts.wizard_2.7.1.201107091000-RELEASE.jar.
>   Read timed out
>   Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/37/update/plugins/org.aspectj.ajde_1.6.12.20110613132200.jar.
>   Read timed out
>   Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/37/update/plugins/org.eclipse.ajdt.ui_2.1.3.e37x-20110628-1900.jar.
>   Read timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution was to install the SpringIde from  spring itself, it comes as an eclipse install with spring already installed.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem when i select the all plugins but when i have selected only:

Core/Spring IDE
Extension(Incubation) /Spring IDE
Resource /Spring IDE

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/how-to-install-spring-ide-in-eclipse/

Then it has easily installed ....

Hope this will help any one ,who is facing the problem .............

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to resolve the terrible Internet connection. Because P2 considers the Socket timeout as fatal error if the repository doesn't have mirror sites. See bug [350014](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350014) for detail.

But P2 already cached the successful downloaded artifacts, you can restart your Installation process to continue to download other artifacts from the repository.

And spring depends on the AJDT from eclipse.org, you can directly install AJDT from the built-in Indigo repository that has a lot of mirrors to speed up downloading jars.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem installing the Spring IDE on my Indigo Eclipse. It took a long time to resolve dependencies and kept timing out.

I solved by fixing my proxy settings. I had to clear my proxy entries for the socks connection (just had the http and https entries defined). I remember I didn't have to do this for previous versions of Eclipse.

But it was painless after that, I used Eclipse marketplace to search for Spring Ide and installed it from there. It took about 5 minutes for the whole installation to complete.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding these lines to eclipse.ini solved the problem

```
-vmargs (this one was already there)
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```