# Installation of Force.com IDE Error

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, apex-code

Eclipse Version is Helios SR2 64bit running on Linux Ubuntu.

I'm trying to install Force.com IDE plugin and I'm getting the following error.  I believe Salesforce uses the pulse engine, I've searched for others having this problem but the only solution I've found so far is just install the force.com ide bundled version of Eclipse.  Which I would rather not do.

Error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
   session context was:(profile=epp.package.java,    
   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.log4j,1.2.15.v201005080500
   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.402.v201102031915
   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.502.v201101122002
   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.404.v201101190004
   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui,1.0.504.v201101122108
```

Comment: try to install WTP from Helio repository.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, WTP is already installed

Comment: Did read about some errors similar to this.  Didn't quite understand but had to do with Equinox OSGI bundle.

Comment: You can check the .log of your eclipse to see more detail errors. I think it's probably similar with the case I answered in another post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025486/help-installing-spring-plugin-on-eclipse-indigo/7027457#7027457

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced this myself, but according to [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/Google-Web-Toolkit/2011-02/msg01919.html) of a guy having the same error with a different plugin (GWT), his solution was

> answering my own question: not sure why this happened, but gwt is not
>   the problem.
>   what i did to fix was to edit the url of each checked site and add
>   a // at the end.
>   install ran fine afterwards.

Guess it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, tried that didn't work for me, complains that plug-in cannot be found if I // at the end of the url.